# How to Change Floating TextField Default Placeholder Color in IOS Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have used Floating Text Field in my application. In don't know how to change the default placeholder color in ios. I have attached screenshot there the password default color is gray, I have to change the password color as black. If any text is entered in the entry that time only the password color is changed as black.

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: you will propably need to create a CustomRenderer for the Entry. You can create a class that derives from the iOS original textField, something like:  myTextField : UITextField then you can add your own properties and also modify the placeholder attribute that UITextField have. After that, you create a var txt = new myTextField()

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Calvin Nunes. I am using custom renderer. And its working fine. But i have to change the default placeholder gray color. I used the below code to my Appdelegate but it is not reflecting. var t = new UITextField() { AttributedPlaceholder = new NSAttributedString("", null, UIColor.Red) };

Comment: aah, sorry, I read it fast and let the word 'color' pass away... sorry, but it will be more difficult and probably I'm not able to help because I'm not very skillful with xamarin.iOS

Comment: Are you using Xamarin.Forms's Entry control?

Comment: @ Kevin Li, Yes I have used Xamarin.Forms's Entry

Comment: Don't you see the property `PlaceholderColor` on Entry?

Comment: @Cole Xia, Entry has placeholder color property, this placeholder color is working fine when any text is entered in Entry. My issue is about how to change the default placeholder color (Gray to any other color). When any text is not entered in entry the default placeholder color is gray as shown in the screenshot. In my screenshot the username default placeholder color is gray when i enter any text to user name it changed as black, but the below password placeholder color is gray. How to change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the problem was caused that the logic in `MaterialEntryRenderer`.

Find the method `SetPlaceholderColor` , it changes the placeholderColr rendering.

Modify it as below:

```
private void SetPlaceholderColor()
{
    if (Element.PlaceholderColor == Color.Default)
    {
        Control.FloatingLabelTextColor = _defaultPlaceholderColor;
        Control.AttributedPlaceholder = new NSAttributedString(Control.Placeholder, new UIStringAttributes { ForegroundColor = _defaultPlaceholderColor });
    }
    else {
        Control.FloatingLabelTextColor = Element.PlaceholderColor.ToUIColor();
        Control.AttributedPlaceholder = new NSAttributedString(Control.Placeholder, new UIStringAttributes { ForegroundColor = Element.PlaceholderColor.ToUIColor() });
    }
}
```

Then you can change the placeholder color as you want .

```
var userNameEntry = new Entry()
{
    Placeholder = "UserName",
    PlaceholderColor = Color.Red,
    TextColor = Color.Green,
};

var passwordEntry = new Entry()
{
    Placeholder = "Password",
    PlaceholderColor = Color.Black,
    TextColor = Color.Gray,
};
```

[image]