# How to Hide Tabbar Top Border color in IOS Xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have Changed the Tabbar selected text color by using the below code. But I don't know how to hide the tabbar top border color in xamarin.forms ios.

```
 UITabBar.Appearance.SelectedImageTintColor = UIColor.FromRGB(247, 148, 30);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set this in `AppDelegate` , it works perfectly on my side.

```
UITabBar.Appearance.BackgroundImage = new UIImage();
UITabBar.Appearance.ShadowImage = new UIImage();
```

Comment: Glad to help you . and have you solved this problem ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47552910/how-to-change-floating-textfield-default-placeholder-color-in-ios-xamarin-forms

Comment: No @Cole Xia. Please check the sample file and give any suggestion to fix this issue. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YAy8dyufFHt_op9KYpRtnZlhpjgLhVvE